# REST API to identify Stable Maven Version of any Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, alpha, beta, sonatype

Do we have any REST API from Sonatype that gives long tern stable Maven Version excluding apha and beta versions from Maven web repository.
If anyone knows any other API please comment.

I have written a code based on timestamp to get the latest stable version.

Comment: There is a rest api on Sonatype Nexus?

Comment: usually, alpha and beta versions have a prefix, so you could check for the latest package without that prefix

Comment: How do you define “long term stable”?

Answer (score 0):

The point is: There is no standardized way to use version numbers, only some usual approaches. Stable versions are often called `1.2.3` or `1.2.3.Final` or similar.

So you will not be able to fully automate this.